# Proving that 2 non equal edges are equal using vectors.

Tags: vectors

I was solving some vector problems when I came upon this problem, where I have a triangle with a median that is not isosceles, and I proved that it is isosceles.

So how is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go from the third line to the fourth, you lose a minus sign.  $DC=-CD$ as vectors.